# UIView not sliding up from the bottom

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I'm trying to get a `UIView` to slide up from the bottom of the screen. I created the `UIView` as a separate nib file. I'm initially adding the view beyond the view port of the screen and then animating the `y` value to have it slide up.

```
self.bannerView = BannerView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: self.view.bounds.height, width: self.view.bounds.width - 10, height: 44))
self.collectionView?.addSubview(self.bannerView!)

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
    self.bannerView?.frame.origin.y = self.bannerView!.frame.origin.y - 64
}
```

However it doesn't seem to work. The view is not showing up. But the calculations seem to be correct. I can't figure out what's wrong.

Example project uploaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/96zxdyqo14i0qjr/BottomBanner.zip?dl=0).

Comment: Are you just pushing it off the screen more with your math?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to change the entire `frame` instead of just the `y` value - which will not work.

As an illustration - you can refer to https://youtu.be/2kwCfFG5fDA?list=PL0dzCUj1L5JGKdVUtA5xds1zcyzsz7HLj&t=993 wherein exactly your problem has been demonstrated to be working by changing frame. The example is above video is also in `Swift` thus suiting to your need in the question.

Answer (score 1):

One line solution:

```
self.bannerView?.frame = self.bannerView!.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: -64)
```

(paste this inside the animation block)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't validated your math but try to set the entire frame instead of changing a property of the assigned frame since that won't work.

```
var frame = self.bannerView!.frame
frame.origin.y = frame.origin.y - 64
self.bannerView?.frame = frame
```